# Can't figure out the syntax for a where clause

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a report that contains the following parameter "Fine > 0" and the choices are "Yes", "No" and both using a multi-select dropdown box.  The parameter gets passed to the stored procedure as either "Yes', "No" or "Yes, No".

In the SP has syntax similar to this

```
Case WHEN @FineAmount = 'Yes' THEN I.Fine > 0 
WHEN @FineAmount = 'No' Then I.Fine = 0
ELSE I.Fine >= 0
    END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some case logic that will get the job done.

```
where
  I.Fine > case
    when @FineAmount like '%Yes%' then 0
    else I.Fine + 1 end
  or I.Fine = case
    when @FineAmount like '%No%' then 0
    else I.Fine - 1 end
```

Comment: Wow, thank you.  For some reason I could not get my head around this problem this morning.